# Continuity of a claim exponentially distributed

Tags: continuity, self-learning

I have the following exercise:

The occurence of a claim follows an exponential distribution with mean 4000. The insurance imposes an upper limit of 6000 for coverage in the policy. If a claim occurs for sure, the payment of the policy has the following cdf:

F(x) =

0 if x <0

1-e^(-x/4000) if 0 ≤ x < 6000

1 if x≥6000.

a) Check at which points F is continuous. Draw a graph of the function.

b)Bonus question(useful for next semester): Compute the expectation of the loss.

I want to be sure if my way to check for continuity is right. For me a function is continuous at point c if f(c) = lim x->c f(x). So in that case:

- f(0)= 0, lim x->0 f(x)= lim x-> 1-e^(-x/4000)=0 (e to the power 0 = 1).

--> So in that case the function is continuous at x=0

- f(6000)=1, lim x->6000 f(x)= lim x->6000 1-e^(-6000/4000)= 0.776

--> So in that case the function is discontinuous at x=6000

I'm scared I missed something by not checking for each situation the limit from the right and the limit from the left. Am I right to do so ?

Comment: At $x=6000$, you have correctly computed the left limit, but the left and right limits will not be the same. (You also need to remark that $f$ will be continuous away from the "break points" $x=0$ and $x=6000$. For your purposes this can probably just be stated rather than needing to prove it.)

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand the difference. Is not lim x->+6000 f(x) simply 1 in my case ? If yes i just need to read that info or is there a more scientific way to find it ?

Comment: To state it right, can I simply write: 

The domain of f(x) is = (-∞ , 6000[ U [6000,+∞)

Comment: $x$ can get arbitrarily close to $6000$ from the left. Along that path, you take a limit of $f$ and you're using the second case of it, so you get $1-e^{-6000/4000}$. $x$ can also get arbitrarily close to $6000$ from the right. Along that path, you take a limit of $f$ and you're using the third case of it, so you get $1$. This is really easy to see in a graph.